# What does "with the weary resignation of a century's hindsight" mean?

Tags: meaning

> At least the city was not torched, wrote the historian Jordanes **with the weary resignation of a century's hindsight**.

This sentence comes from a  description of Rome being stormed by VisiGothians in the book [*The Silk Roads: A New History of the World*](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=M1FFCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT54&lpg=PT54&dq=%22At+least+the+city+was+not+torched%22&source=bl&ots=QtNlODAOPs&sig=ACfU3U1JG3KzPB6qDqa_vOc0_UN65AcaUQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv39PoiIT3AhW7yYsBHYeWD88Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22At%20least%20the%20city%20was%20not%20torched%22&f=false) by Peter Frankopan.

What does it mean to say,

> with the weary resignation of a century's hindsight.

Comment: We try to help those who first help themselves. How might you interpret the quotation yourself?

Answer (score 2):

I had to look up [Jordanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordanes), but apparently he lived in the sixth century; more than 100 years after the sack of Rome by the Visigoths. He was therefore writing in the knowledge of another century of historical events, no doubt including occasions when cities *had* been burned after being taken by storm.

Comment: not clear understanding: including occassions when cities had been burned after being taken by storm

Comment: Between 410 when the Visigoths sacked Rome and the 550s when Jordanes was writing, there had probably been some (many?) occasions when cities had been stormed _and_ burned (unlike Rome which escaped being burned). He was resigned to the fact that this was an all-too-common occurrence.